# pylint disabling a single line of code just produces another pylint error

Tags: python, pylint

The documentation in section 4.1 clearly states:

https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#message-control

> 4.1 Is it possible to locally disable a particular message?

Yes, this feature has been added in Pylint 0.11. This may be done by adding “#pylint: disable=some-message,another-one” at the desired block level or at the end of the desired line of code

---

Great! but it doesn't work. Boo.

I get the the following pylint error for the following line of code

```
W: 26, 2: Redefining built-in 'zip' (redefined-builtin)
```

```py
try:
  from itertools import izip as zip  # pylint: disable=bad-builtin
except ImportError:
  pass
```

But pylint just complains even louder about my attempt to shut it up:

```
E: 26, 0: Bad option value 'bad-builtin' (bad-option-value)
```

I've also tried the error code `# pylint: disable=W0141`, that also produces a similar error.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Strange, I run the same code and get no error....

Comment: That is strange. Perhaps a change from one version to another?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have been in a similar situation.

### Unsolvable pylint issue

```
class A:
    pass
```

There are many warnings in `pylint` for the code above, but I want to talk about `old-style-class`.
In Python 2.7, you will get an `old-style-class` error.
Of course, you can change your code like this:

```
class A(object):
    pass
```

However, you will receive a `useless-object-inheritance` warning in Python 3.

If you are writing a package compatible with python 2.7 and 3 and using `pylint`, then you are down.

### Unavoidable bad-option-value

Yes, if it is accepted to disable either of `old-style-class` or `useless-object-inheritance` in a comment, you can go further.

In Python 2.7:

```
# pylint: disable=old-style-class
class A:
    pass
```

In Python 3:

```
# pylint: disable=useless-object-inheritance
class A(object):
    pass
```

Eventually, you will get a `bad-option-value`, just the same as this question.

### Disable bad-option-value

I have tried, but `bad-option-value` can not be disabled locally in this case.
I have to disable `bad-option-value` in a `pylint` configuration file, like `.pylintrc`.

```
[TYPECHECK]
disable=bad-option-value
```

**Note**: My `pylint` version is 1.9.4 in python 2.7, 2.2.2 in python 3.

Answer (score 3):

Ah, simple answer, it should be `# pylint: disable=bad-option-value` which is presented in the error message in parenthesis:

```
E: 26, 0: Bad option value 'bad-builtin' (bad-option-value)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get this message:

```
W: 26, 2: Redefining built-in 'zip' (redefined-builtin)
```

You have to disable the exact error message you are getting (the one in parenthesis):

```
try:
  from itertools import izip as zip  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
except ImportError:
  pass
```

That seems to work fine in pylint 2.5.

It can be annoying if you are testing with multiple versions of python or different venvs and the same code base and you get different errors.   Be sure you fix the version to one version across all your builds/tests.  It sounds like that may have happened here (not sure where you got `bad-builtin` from).